# Annotate queryset with previous object in Django ORM

Tags: sql, django-queryset, django-orm

Example models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass


class UserStatusChange(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='status_changes')
    status = models.CharField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

I want to annotate `UserStatusChanges` queryset with `end_date` field, and `end_date` should be equal to `start_date` of next status change for the same user.

Eventually, I want to be able to do this:

```
qs = UserStatusChange.ojects.annotate(end_date=???)
qs = qs.filter(start_date__lte=some_date, end_date__gte=another_date)
```

Logically that annotation should be something like this:

```
qs.annotate(
    end_date=qs.filter(
        user=OuterRef('user'),
        start_date__gt=OuterRef('start_date')
    ).order_by('start_date').first().start_date)
```

But it should be one DB query, if it is possible.

**Solution:**

```
subquery = UserStatusChange.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('user'),
                                           start_date__gt=OuterRef('start_date')).order_by('start_date')
UserStatusChange.objects.annotate(end_date=Subquery(subquery.values('start_date')[:1]))
```

That works, thank to @hynekcer's answer. But with `aggregate` I got the error:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

**UPD**: in Django 2.0+ it can be solved with [Lead Window function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#lead).
In SQL it will be something like this:

```
select 
     user_id, status_id, start_date,
     LEAD(start_date, 1) over (partition by user_id order by start_date)
from user_status_change;
```

Comment: What you want to get? What you mean by `user=F('user')? It will be compilad to `app_userstatusshange.user=app_userstatusshange.user` that is not what you expected probably.

Comment: @hynekcer that I want to select status changes for the same user.

Comment: @hynekcer every `UserStatusChanges` is related to some specific user. So when I want to annotate `UserStatusChanges` with `end_date` that `end_date` should be related to previous change for some user. So, finally, I have to do this:
`qs = UserStatusChanges.ojects.annotate(end_date=???)`
`qs = qs.filter(start_date__lte=some_date, end_date__gte=another_date)`
`User.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('status_changes', queryset=qs))`

It means that I need to get list of users with **their own** change events filtered by date range.

Comment: Is it OK that `end_date < start_date`? I implemented it how you wrote, but my sense for question purpose would to rename e.g. to "previous_date" or to define end_date as a date of the next status.

Comment: @hynekcer no, `end_date` will not be less than `start_date`

Comment: If you want annotate `end_date` to "be related to previous change for some user" then it is less than `start_date`. I was hoping that you will fix the verbal part of question to be clear and I could up vote it as useful for other people and remove my comments.

Comment: It seems that switch/case is also required, since last status change doesn't have next event.

Comment: It is simpler to use Coalesce():`...Coalesce(Min('start_date'), now())`. I'm going to edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Subquery()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) with OuterRef() in Django 1.11.

```
from django.db.models import Min, OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

default_end = now()  # or the end of the recorded history
qs = (
    UserStatusChanges.objects
    .annotate(
        end_date=Coalesce(
            Subquery(
                UserStatusChanges.objects
                .filter(
                    user=OuterRef('user'),
                    start_date__gt=OuterRef('start_date')
                )
                .order_by()
                .aggregate(Min('start_date'))
            ),
            default_end
        )
    )
)
qs = qs.order_by('user', 'start_date')
# an optional filter
qs = qs.filter(start_date__lte=some_date, end_date__gte=another_date, user__in=[...])
```

It is compiled as one query when being executed, e.g. when combined with User filter by prefetch_related. If you want a meaningful `end_date` also for the last item then you can use [`Coalesce()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) with a default value equal to the current timestamp.